# Angular Pipe to display tooltip when text is not fully visible

Tags: angular

I want to display tooltip if text is not fully displayed in view.

I tried two methods

1. I wrote a function to calculate scrollWidth & clientWidth and conditionally show tooltip. [Working well].
2. I wrote similar logic in pipe (not working)

```html
<br><br><br><br>

<!-- It is working well with function getToolTip -->
<div class="text-limit-10rem" #firstDiv [ngbTooltip]="getToolTip(longMessage, firstDiv)">
  {{longMessage}}
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="text-limit-10rem" #secondDiv [ngbTooltip]="getToolTip(shortMessage, secondDiv)">
  {{shortMessage}}
</div>

<br><br><br>

<!-- It's not working when I'm using pipe -->
<div class="text-limit-10rem color-red" #thirdDiv [ngbTooltip]="longMessage | widthPipe: thirdDiv">
  {{longMessage}}
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="text-limit-10rem color-red" #forthDiv [ngbTooltip]="shortMessage | widthPipe: forthDiv">
  {{shortMessage}}
</div>
```

```js
  getToolTip(strVal, element: Element){
    if(element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth){
      console.log('From Method: Scroll Width ', element.scrollWidth, ' Client Width ',element.clientWidth);
      return strVal;
    }
    else {
      return ''
    };
  }
```

Pipe

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'widthPipe'
})
export class WidthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(strVal: string, elem: Element): string {
    console.log('From Pipe Scroll Width ', elem.scrollWidth, ' Client Width ',elem.clientWidth);
    if (elem.scrollWidth > elem.clientWidth) {
      return strVal && strVal.trim().length > 0 ? strVal : '';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.text-limit-10rem {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 10rem;
    background-color: YELLOW;
}
```

[image]

[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpfmrr)

If any one know a better way to show tooltip only when text is not fully visible, kindly comment.

Comment: is easy with css : 
```.font-resiz {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
} ```
In HTML ex :
```<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{longMessage}}">
            <div class="font-resiz">{{longMessage}}</div>
    </span>
```

Comment: I've updated question with my existing CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless whether or not it's best practice. The reason your pipe is not working, is because the method defined inside is not 'pure'. Which means, the same input into the pipe, will not produce the same output, because it depends on an external object. The window object in this case.

You can fix this by using `pure: false`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'widthPipe',
  pure: false
})
export class WidthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  //...
}
```

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4geqf?file=src/app/width.pipe.ts)

However, it might be better to create a separate component or directive for this, so that you can listen for a window resize to recalculate. An unpure pipe is usually a performance issue

Comment: I wanted to remove `getToolTip` function call in html template because of performance issue. Can you please suggest which will better for this use case `Component` or `Directive`

Comment: @Chenna A directive would be best. You can use `ElementRef` to get the element it's attached to

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

slice-with-tooltip.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'slice-with-tooltip',
    templateUrl: './slice-with-tooltip.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./slice-with-tooltip.component.less'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class SliceWithTooltipComponent {
    @Input() text: string;
    @Input() limit: number = 20;
}
```

slice-with-tooltip.component.html

```html
<div>
    <span>{{ text | slice: 0:limit }}</span>
    <span class="show-more" *ngIf="text && text.length > limit" [pTooltip]="text">
        ...
    </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can done that with css as well. Just make a css class like below and it will do the same thing.

```
.text-limit-10rem{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```